# Analytical hierarchy process tool - SAGA. How to configure Pairwise comparisons table?

Tags: qgis-2, saga, table, tools

What is the configuration and extension (.txt, .csv ...) of the Pairwise comparisons table file requested by the SAGA AHP tool- Analytical Hierarchy Process - in QGIS? Are there examples of applications available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, working with SAGA through QGIS 2.18 Processing Toolbox would be safer than the latest QGIS 3 (I appreciate your `[qgis-2]` tag for that reason).

You can use any text format to create the Pairwise Comparisons Table, as far as it can be read by QGIS. I would suggest csv format, as I can just drag and drop it onto QGIS window.

(1) Create csv file;

Please make sure you have one header row, which indicates each input layer. Also note the order of the row (rows 2, 3, 4 in this example) should follow the same layer order. (I mean, row number 2 represents Layer1).

[image]

(2) Drag and drop the above csv file onto QGIS

[image]

(3) Start **Analytical hierarchy process** tool and;

(3A)....... select the layer in the order according to the table

(3B)....... select the table layer as the `Pairwise Comparison Table`.

then, Run the tool.

Comment: The Analytical Hierarchi Process tool with the suggested table worked fine in QGIS 2.14.18.
On the other hand, in QGIS 2.18.27 the SAGA tool has responded:
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details

Comment: @Sergio QGIS 2.18.27 works for me. Double check your workflow.

Comment: I understand that the table works fine in QGIS 2.18.27 as well. However, I noticed that in my machine several SAGA tools fail in QGIS 2.18.27, among them: raster calculator, analytical hierarchy process, reclassify values ... and so on.
Always with the same answer: _'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details_.
I would appreciate it if you can help me with this problem too.

Comment: @Sergio Have you searched this site with `[mac]` `[saga]` tags? If you find no solution then you can post a new question.